# MFC: OnNcCreate() not called; need to set BS_OWNERDRAW flag for CButton subclass

Tags: mfc, ownerdrawn, cbutton

I'm not an expert on MFC, but I've made a dozen or so custom controls over the last 15+ years.  I've just made a `CButton` with custom graphics.

Here's the problem: Of course I need `BS_OWNERDRAW` to be set.  I have an `OnNcCreate()` method I've cut and pasted for 15+ years that's always worked in my custom controls, but for some reason it's not now being called.

I have no interest or even understanding of `OnNcCreate()` except for the fact that it was the place I ended up getting `BS_OWNERDRAW` set the first time I tried writing a custom control.

**Question: What would keep `OnNcCreate()` from being called?  Or, is there another place I could or should be setting `BS_OWNERDRAW` ?**

A working class is defined with:

```
class CGood : public CStatic {
```

The non-working one is defined with:

```
class CBad : public CButton {
```

They both prototype the method thusly:

```
afx_msg int     OnNcCreate( LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct );
```

The method is written identically (except the class name):

```
int CGood::OnNcCreate( LPCREATESTRUCT pcrs ) {

  wStyleBits = LOWORD( pcrs->style );

  DWORD dwStyleSuperclass = MAKELONG( ES_LEFT, HIWORD( pcrs->style ) );

  dwStyleSuperclass |= BS_OWNERDRAW;

  ::SetWindowLong( m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, dwStyleSuperclass );

  pcrs->style = dwStyleSuperclass;

  return CStatic::OnNcCreate( pcrs );
}
```

The dialog is using both the good and bad classes utilizing the Visual Studio 2017 dialog editor, as CustomControl.  Both the good and bad classes have Extended Style 0x0 and Style 0x50010000.  Both er Disabled=False, Help ID=False, Visible=True, Class=Good or Bad as needed.

When run the application calls each class's `RegisterControlClass()` method:

```
static WNDPROC pfnWndProc = NULL;

BOOL CBad::RegisterControlClass() {

  WNDCLASS wcls;
  static const TCHAR szClass[] = _T( "CBad" );

  if ( ::GetClassInfo( AfxGetInstanceHandle(), szClass, &wcls ) )
      return wcls.lpfnWndProc == ( WNDPROC ) CBad::WndProcHook;

  VERIFY( ::GetClassInfo( NULL, _T( "button" ), &wcls ) );
  pfnWndProc = wcls.lpfnWndProc;

  wcls.lpfnWndProc   = CBad::WndProcHook;
  wcls.hInstance     = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
  wcls.lpszClassName = szClass;

  return RegisterClass( &wcls ) != 0;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK EXPORT CBad::WndProcHook( HWND hWnd, UINT msg,
                                              WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {

  CBad* pthis = new CBad();
  pthis->Attach( hWnd );

  pthis->m_pfnSuper = pfnWndProc;
  ::SetWindowLong( hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, ( DWORD )AfxWndProc );

#ifdef STRICT
  return ::CallWindowProc( AfxWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
#else
  return ::CallWindowProc( ( FARPROC )AfxWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
#endif
}
```

(Funny: I note in `CGood`, derived from `CStatic`, mistakenly has "button" there and works fine; it stops working if I change to "static" .  I'll look into that later.  The bad class has "button" and indeed is a `CButton` subclass.)

**Things I've done to confirm the issue:** When I remove the `BS_OWNERDRAW` from the `CGood::OnNcCreate()`, it stops calling `DrawItem()`.  So I'm sure that's the place this flag is being set.

Putting a breakpoint in `CGood::OnNcCreate()` and `CBad::OnNcCreate(),` the CBad one simply isn't called.

I've found examples on the internet of setting `BS_OWNERDRAW` in `PreSubclassWindow()`, `OnCreate()`, and `CreateEx()`, none of which work, in some cases for reasons I think I understand.  (EG you can't just set flags in OnCreate() and call the superclass method, because it is ultimately getting the flags not from the param you give it but from some other source.)

I've tried changing CBad's superclass to CStatic and still the OnNcCreate() isn't being called.

I've tried setting `BS_OWNERDRAW` in the dialog's `OnInitDialog()` and that **does** get the CBad button subclass painting correctly.  So I know I'm not accidently creating them with some other subclass, etc.

```
CBad* pcbut = (CBad*) GetDlgItem( IDC_MARKCHECK );
pcbut->ModifyStyle(0, BS_OWNERDRAW);
```

Comment: _"I need BS_OWNERDRAW to be set"_ -- Not necessarily. Alternative is [Custom Draw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/nm-customdraw-button), which doesn't require you to change any button style bits.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh!  I simply forgot to add it to the message map!

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP( CBad, CButton )
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP( CBad )
    ON_WM_NCCREATE()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```